# How to change the default browser to debug with in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, debugging, browser

When you hit F5, the browser windows pops up, how do you set which browser the debugger users in Visual Studio 2008?

**Update 1**
I have looked for the 'Browse with' option and not found it.
[Visual Studio opens the default browser instead of Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79954/visual-studio-opens-default-browser-instead-of-ie)

**Update 2**
If you are already debugging you dont have the 'Browse with' option.

- *Stop debugging and then its there!*

**Update 3**
The accepted answer below is also relevant to changing the default browser to debug with in Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: //Stop debugging and then its there!//  That's the ticket!

Answer (score 109, accepted):

- (In the Project Solution window) Right click a page (.aspx, or on a folder)
- Select Browse With...
- Choose your browser
- Click Set as Default
- Click Browse

[image: context menu screenshot]

Comment: Just to say. For me Browse With appears only on Default.aspx page!

Comment: Also, make sure you are not already debugging or else the 'Browse With' option won't be visible

Answer (score 21):

**ASP.NET** projects:

- Right click a webpage (.aspx, or on a folder)
- Select Browse With...
- Choose your browser
- Click Set as Default
- Click Browse

**ASP.NET MVC 1** projects:

Right click Default.aspx, then follow steps above.

**ASP.NET MVC 2** projects:

As there is no Default.aspx, you need to create a Web Form (right-click project > Add > New Item) and follow the steps above.

Comment: Just a note, make sure you are not in "Debug Mode", as "Browse with" will not appear then.

Comment: Re: ASP.NET 2 - You don't need to create a new project, just a file as @Photon suggests.

Comment: The accepted answer isn't complete without this answer. The point of creating a Web Form to access the "Browse With..." option was vital for me, or I would've never guessed how to do it in my MVC2 project. Thanks a ton!

Comment: In MVC and Visual Studio 2017, you must do that on a .cshtml file

Answer (score 12):

If you use ASP-NET MVC, you need to right-click on Default.ASPX which will have a Browse With menu.

Answer (score 9):

To permanently make Visual Studio open a project in IE without changing the default browser you can do the following:

`Project Properties -> Web -> Start Action`

Start external program: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
Command line arguments: Enter the url of the path to your start page ie http:\localhost\myproject\default.aspx

This won't allow you to debug client side script in Visual Studio though.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using MVC 2 you do not need to create another project, just add component ->  webform to the project then:

> ```
> * Right click the webform  
> * Select Browse With...  
> * Choose your browser  
> * Click Set as Default  
> * Delete the webform
> ```

Answer (score 3):

If you use MVC, you don't have this menu (no "Browse With..." menu)

Create first a normal ASP.NET web site.

Comment: No need, just right-click on the Default.ASPX file and that one file will have the option.

Comment: There is no Default.aspx file in an MVC 4 app as far as I know?

Answer (score 2):

I have passed this problem in VS2012. When I can't find "Browse with.." on the right-click of the project, I found it on File Menu -> Browse with. If it doesn't appear, first you have to click on menu bar, then try open file menu again. If it still doesn't appear, you can just go to Quick Launch on the top right of menu bar then type it "Browse with".

Answer (score 1):

First click show all files. Then in the bin folder choose any xml file and then right click and by selecting 'browse with' select your desired browser.

Answer (score 0):

`In VS 2010 just make the browser as your default broswer in which  you want to run your application and there is no need to set anything in visual studio.` I did it for google chrome and its working for me. I just made google chrome as my default browser and its working fine. I am almost sure that this should work in VS 2008 also.

Answer (score 0):

I find that the `Browse With..` menu item only appears in Visual Studio 2010 when I `Run as administrator`.  And in that case it is available even **while in**  debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this is simply by selecting the arrow next to the Start Debugging:

[image: the Start Debugging]

Then in the Drop Down goto `Web Browser` and select the browser you would like to debug the site with, you can also select `Browse with...` to set the default as explained in other answers.

Answer (score -3):

ie ---> Tools ---->  Internet options -----> Programe ------>  Make Defualt