# How to change default web browser when debug/run a web site?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, browser, default

Currently, as [stated here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/297298/how-to-change-the-default-browser-to-debug-in-visual-studio-2008/297306#297306), I have to `1)` find a web page file and `2)` right click to select `Browse with...` to open the dialog which lets me to configure the web browser to start with.

Is it possible to open that dialog quickly from menu/hotkey/toolbar? Please share.

*More information*

Start with this[image]

Will open this
[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a great Visual Studio Extension for this: “Default Browser Switcher”
http://blog.wovs.com/2010/08/make-it-easy-to-change-default-browser.html

*Update:*

is VS2013, this has been added as a default feature:

[image: Select browser]

Comment: I tried accessing this link today (11/03/2014). Is it removed?

Comment: Actually, in my company, we are still using VS 2010. So, any tip for that?

Answer (score 2):

can you try "ctl" + "shift" + "w" , and set the browser you want as default browser from the browser it self.

please inform me if that was helpful

Comment: No I don't wanna do it that way - I just want to change the browser for uses in Visual Studio only. Thanks anyway.