# Website administration tool not launching

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have built an ASP.NET MVC 3 project. I click on the icon to go to the administration tool website, it doesn't launch on the browser. So I manually click on it so that it is launched in the browser, but I get to `asp.netwebadminfiles/error.aspx`.

I haven't been able to see the web site to create roles, etc.!

What is the matter?

Answer (score 3):

The solution was to set Internet Explorer as the default browser, I used to have Firefox.

I switch it by:

For an ASP.NET MVC 2 project in Visual Studio 2010 I've found that

- you need to have an .aspx file in the root of the project (the folder where also global.asax and web.config is located). Having an .aspx file in any subfolder like "Views" is not sufficient.
- the name of this .aspx file doesn't matter, it isn't necessary to name it default.aspx

Then the context menu offers a *Browse with...* option when right-clicking on this file in Solution Explorer.

Which I took from: [Change Visual Studio Default Browser in an ASP.NET MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032743)

Comment: For very first time it have to be run in IE, then it works in Firefox.