# Visual Studio 2010 Preview in multiple browsers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cross-browser, expression-web

Is there any extension or feature in VS2010 for previewing in multiple browsers (at the same time) the same as there is in Microsoft Expression Web 4? I know there is the "Default Browser Switcher" extension but this only lets you view one browser at a time.
Cheers
Will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution on how to preview a MVC application in multiple browsers by adding a few answers together.
What you do is add an .aspx page into your project and set this as the startup page when you run the project. 
Then with your project set it so that you are automatically redirected to another page, be it "Login" or a "Home" page.
The last step is to use @Walls answer

When you right click on the page to do the "Browse With...", you can set multiple defaults. Once you have added in multiple browsers to the list, you can CTRL Click each one you want (to highlight multiples). Once the desired ones are highlighted, click "Set as Default". From then on, whenever you hit "Browse" it should open in all your "Default" browsers you highlighted.

Now when you run the project it will start up all of your default browsers for testing.

Answer (score 2):

When you right click on the page to do the "Browse With...", you can set multiple defaults.  Once you have added in multiple browsers to the list, you can CTRL Click each one you want (to highlight multiples).  Once the desired ones are highlighted, click "Set as Default".  From then on, whenever you hit "Browse" it should open in all your "Default" browsers you highlighted.

Comment: Thanks that is good. Do you know how I could get this working with MVC applications also? It does not seem to work.

Comment: Not sure how to do it with MVC apps, only knew how to do it for specific files you are trying to Browse. Sorry.

Comment: Thats all good. I will mark your answer up and answer it as correct if no one else has any ideas.

Comment: I was looking around to see if I could find some more answers about your MVC question (which I am not familiar with).  I found this other question on S.O. which seems related.  Check it out, maybe this will solve the other problem you had.
[MVC Apps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032743/change-visual-studio-default-browser-in-an-asp-net-mvc-project)