# ASP.NET Configuration page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

when I try to access the ASP.NET Configuration page from Visual Studio 2008, I fail . I get an error :

"An error was encountered. Please return to the previous page and try again.".

This is the message I get after clicking on Help : "Tool Has Timed Out . As a security measure, the Web Site Administration Tool times out after a period of inactivity. Changes to machine.config or web.config may also result in the tool needing to be restarted. To continue configuring your web site, restart the tool."

how can I solve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the default browser within Visual Studio to internal browser, and attempt to re-launch the tool.  This worked for me.

Comment: and here how to change it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79954/visual-studio-opens-the-default-browser-instead-of-internet-explorer

Answer (score 1):

It's likely the is an error in your web.config file - try making sure the xml is valid, all tags are closed that sort of thing.

Comment: I looked and it seems to be OK.

Comment: Do you get any more details in the error, something starting with a line saying 'The following message may help in diagnosing the problem:'?

Comment: Tool Has Timed Out





This is the message I get after clicking on Help : "As a security measure, the Web Site Administration Tool times out after a period of inactivity. Changes to machine.config or web.config may also result in the tool needing to be restarted. To continue configuring your web site, restart the tool."

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the Event log for possibly more information on the actual underlying error

Answer (score -2):

Edit your Web.config file and add this:

```
 <system.web>
   <authorization>
     <deny users="?"/>
   </authorization>
</system.web>
```