# Is Internet Explorer 11 supported by Worklight?

Tags: windows-8, ibm-mobilefirst, internet-explorer-11

I am working on application for Windows 8 tablet and would like to leverage some features introduced in IE 11.

I am using laptop with Windows 8.1 and IE 11. I was really surprised to see when I was debugging in VS 2013 that my app is running on IE 10 but not IE 11.

I tried to build project in Eclipse setting it up that it should use external browser as it adviced in this article: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21600697 but no luck :-( it still use IE10.

Is there is a way to debug a Windows 8 tablet app in VS 2013 using default browser on laptop? Like IE 11 on Windows 8.1 laptop.

Thank you in advance for help!

Answer (score 0):

The option you tried is not related as it is about Worklight Console's MBS, whereas you are talking about Visual Studio which is an external IDE for Windows Store and Windows Phone 8 app development...

What you want to do is set Internet Explorer 11 as your default browser in your Windows 8 Desktop machine (running Visual Studio). However, that seems to be not so straight forward with Visual Studio in the mix.

Here are some possible solutions:

- [Where does Visual Studio stores the default browser to use in debug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013320/where-does-visual-studio-stores-the-default-browser-to-use-in-debug)
- [Visual Studio opens the default browser instead of Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79954/visual-studio-opens-the-default-browser-instead-of-internet-explorer)
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/2131/set-default-browser-in-visual-studio.aspx

Perhaps this as well:

- http://developer.telerik.com/featured/5-ways-to-build-mobile-apps-with-visual-studio/
- http://blog.credera.com/technology-insights/microsoft-solutions/5-things-you-need-to-know-about-debugging-in-visual-studio-2012/

Comment: Little bit more info: Internet Explorer is in fact my default browser on my machine. I set it explicitly by going to "Set Program Access and Computer Default" at Windows 8.1 "Default Programs".
I came to conclusion that Worklight+Eclipse are responsible for appearing IE10 as my browser in debugging under the VS based on couple of tests:

Comment: 1.  I created the separate test .jsproj in VS using New->Project->JavaScript. It created for me the same type of. jsproj as I have when I do deployment using Worklight. And good news! I got my default IE11 when I was debugging my test project.  Exactly what I need. So, my VS 2013 using default IE11 when debugging JavaScript project created without Worklight but giving me IE10 when I debug Worklight project.

Comment: 2. When I am debugging in VS my Worklight project I am getting is IE10, which is not installed in my machine. It looks for me that I am getting some framework internal browser when debugging Worklight project with VS. That is why I was trying to switch to external browser before deploying Worklight project in eclipse.
Any thoughts on that?