# how to test my asp.net program on explorer?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008

i work on visual-studio 2008 and my default web browser is google chrome.

i want to test it on explorer.

when i run from visual-studio it shows on google chrome.

how to change it ?

Comment: Duplicate post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79954/visual-studio-opens-default-browser-instead-of-ie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scott Gu [blogged](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/11/18/430943.aspx) about this.