# is there a way to set a default browser for visual studio to use for debugging that is different than my systems default browser?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, browser

is there a way to set a default browser for visual studio to use for debugging that is different than my systems default browser? im using Visual studio 2010, my systems default browser is chrome but i want VS to use firefox

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right click on a .aspx page in your solution explorer->Browse With...->Set as Default

Answer (score 1):

Found this link: [Visual Studio opens the default browser instead of Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79954/visual-studio-opens-default-browser-instead-of-ie)

Basically it sounds like you just need to add whatever web browser you want to use to a particular list. This is done by selecting a web page file and then defining what browser to use.