# Is there a way to build an application which runs Firefox as the default browser in vs 2015?

Tags: c#, iis, web-applications, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to build a web app but when I run app it's opening IE as a default and some assets are not showing and it buffers and when I run the app with other browsers everything displays.

Answer (score 2):

If the application is a Web Application then you will be able to see a Run symbol with the installed browsers listed as drop down. The default will be selected as Internet Explorer. You can change the behavior by choosing the listed browser and run the application.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what are you asking, but I think this may help you:

[is there a way to set a default browser for visual studio to use for debugging that is different than my systems default browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4707393/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-default-browser-for-visual-studio-to-use-for-debugging-t)

> Right click on a .aspx page in your solution explorer->Browse With...->Set as Default

Another response would be

[Visual Studio opens the default browser instead of Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79954/visual-studio-opens-the-default-browser-instead-of-internet-explorer)

> 1) Right click on a .aspx page in your solution explorer
>
> 2) Select the "browse with" context menu option
>
> 3) In the dialog you can select or add a browser. If you want Firefox in the list, click "add" and point to the firefox.exe filename
>
> 4) Click the "Set as Default" button to make this the default browser when you run any page on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps:

> 1st, Open your Firefox browser.
>
> 2nd, Select "Tools."
>
> 3rd, Select "Options."
>
> 4th, Select the Advanced tab
>
> 5th, Check the box next to "Always check to see if Firefox is the
>   default browser on startup."
>
> 6th, Select "Check Now."
>
> 7th, Select "Yes."
>
> 8th, Click "OK."

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have control over your user audience, then this has highlighted an area in your app that needs attention, since you will have to cater for at least the popular browsers (I.E., Chrome, Firefox, Safari etc).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for option in Visual Studio than it is near run and debug option

And if you wanna detect this by code than you should check this post 

 
[Browser detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2221722/browser-detection)