# Visual studio loose default browser setting after reopening visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, default-browser

I found couple of questions in SO where we can change default browser setting in visual studio.

[Visual Studio opens the default browser instead of Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79954/visual-studio-opens-the-default-browser-instead-of-internet-explorer)

And that works fine. But when i close and open the visual studio then visual studio opens the default browser instead of Internet explorer. Is there any way we can set IE as default browser no matter we close and open visual studio?

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79954/visual-studio-opens-the-default-browser-instead-of-internet-explorer) contains tips on how to do it on a webforms project as well as mvc 1/2/3. Just make sure you read the comments there and other answers with high votes.

Comment: @vonv. : I have already mentioned that link in my question. But none of the answers say anything about visual studio loose default browser setting after reopening visual studio.

Comment: Which version of VS?