# Visual Studio 2013 debugging in opera 18

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, opera

not sure if this counts as an SO question, but lets give it a shot.

I have upgraded my Opera browser from v16 to the new chromium based browser (v18), and since then if I try debug an asp.net system in Opera Visual Studio throws up the following error

```
Unable to start program "http://localhost:3601/testpage.aspx. A null reference pointer was 
passed to the stub
```

Has anyone hit this one before?

I have noticed the following

1. Everything runs as normal if I use IE or Chrome
2. If I run without debugging (ctrl+f5) the app runs fine

any suggestions? This is one of those silly things that is driving me nuts. I have tried reinstalling Opera, Visual studio. just seems like something isn't compatible

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439072/null-reference-pointer-was-passed-to-the-stub-when-not-debugging-with-ie

Comment: Thanks. Duplicate indeed. But answered didn't help. Ill need the silver light debugging eventually

Comment: What happens when you ctrl-f5 start the app and then attach the debugger?