# Why am I getting this exception when using CommonOpenFileDialog in a Console Application?

Tags: c#, dialog, openfiledialog, windows-api-code-pack

### The Problem

I'm trying to use CommonOpenFileDialog's folder picker, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41511598/3658757). The problem is that even with a very stripped down example project I get an exception when trying to use CommonOpenFileDialog's `ShowDialog()` function.

### The Code

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;

namespace DialogTest
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CommonOpenFileDialog dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
            dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users";
            dialog.IsFolderPicker = true;

            CommonFileDialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
            {
                //Do Stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm also using the following nuget packages, with author Microsoft:

- Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Core
- Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack-Shell

### The Exception

This code produces the following exception at `dialog.ShowDialog();`:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled
  ErrorCode=-2147023116
  HResult=-2147023116
  Message=A null reference pointer was passed to the stub. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706F4)
  Source=Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.IFileDialog.SetFileName(String pszName)
       at Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.CommonFileDialog.ApplyNativeSettings(IFileDialog dialog) in c:\projects\Windows API Code Pack 1.1\source\WindowsAPICodePack-NuGet\Shell\CommonFileDialogs\CommonFileDialog.cs:line 768
       at Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs.CommonFileDialog.ShowDialog() in c:\projects\Windows API Code Pack 1.1\source\WindowsAPICodePack-NuGet\Shell\CommonFileDialogs\CommonFileDialog.cs:line 609
       at DialogTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\users\obscerno\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication2\ConsoleApplication2\Program.cs:line 13
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

### Some Other Relevant Details

1. I'm using Visual Studio 2015.
2. One strange thing about this error is that this code was working a year ago. I just re-opened the project planning to make some small changes and it was no longer functioning.
3. On creating a new test project, on the first run I'm prompted by Visual Studio to locate a file called `CommonFileDialog.cs`.

   The initial directory that it checks for the file at is "c:\projects\Windows API Code Pack 1.1\source\WindowsAPICodePack-NuGet\Shell\CommonFileDialogs\CommonFileDialog.cs" which does not exist on my computer.

   If I select "cancel" the prompt does not return during future debugs. I suspect this missing file is the source of the problem, but don't know what to do with this information.

### What I've Tried

1. Searching the exception didn't turn up much of anything, aside from [this amusing but irrelevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19439072/null-reference-pointer-was-passed-to-the-stub-when-not-debugging-with-ie).
2. Installing the same nuget packages from multiple sources didn't give me any different results. There are quite a few copies of the packages because [for a while Microsoft made them unavailable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24081665/windows-api-code-pack-where-is-it).
3. I tried searching my computer for the file "CommonFileDialog.cs" but it's nowhere to be found.

Comment: can you try to put the attribute [STAThread] in front of your Main?

Comment: @trykyn thank you so much, that did the trick! Can you please post this as an answer so I can mark this question as solved?

Comment: @trykyn also, if you know why this became necessary only in the last year I'd be interested in learning why. No worries if not though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [trykyn mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56892605/why-am-i-getting-this-exception-when-using-commonopenfiledialog#comment100347312_56892605), the solution to this problem is to add `[STAThread]` in front of the Main.

The working code can be seen below. Note that it requires a call to `System`.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;

namespace DialogTest
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CommonOpenFileDialog dialog = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
            dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\Users";
            dialog.IsFolderPicker = true;

            CommonFileDialogResult result = dialog.ShowDialog();

            if (result == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
            {
                //Do Stuff
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For more information on what STAThread is, this answer goes over it in detail: [What does [STAThread] do?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1361048/3658757)

> The STAThreadAttribute is essentially a requirement for the Windows message pump to communicate with COM components. Although core Windows Forms does not use COM, many components of the OS such as system dialogs do use this technology.