# Visual studio 2013 performance wizard, change default browser

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

When I launch the performance wizard, it opens Internet Explorer. But I want to use Google Chrome instead. Here is how I open the performance wizard. There is no menu for choosing browser.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: why does it matter? This is server side performance, the browser doesn't matter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio opens the default browser instead of Internet Explorer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79954/visual-studio-opens-the-default-browser-instead-of-internet-explorer)

Comment: it metters becouse for some reason,application doesn't work in internet exploler for now,but works in other browsers.Becouse of ajax function.

Comment: No it is not dublicate,in these quastion was asked about debug application browser,no about performane wizard.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach it to a process. On the Performance Explorer:

1. Right click on the project
2. Attach/Detach
3. Select what is running the project - w3wp.exe for IIS or iisexpress.exe for IIS Express. If you don't see any of them you should tick both checkboxes (Show processes for all users / Show Processes in all sessions